# Removing CSS class not yielding expected results with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, removeclass

I have a web site that exists on one page: index.html. There is a lot of content on the site (that appears to be on many "pages") but via javascript and CSS, all the info is contained on index.html.

So there exists a "home" position and an "inside" position (like a home page and inside page), and I need some links to behave differently when the user is on an inside page vs the home page. So the way I have it set up, once an "inside" link is clicked, I remove a class from a div that I *think* should cause the links within that div to behave differently. But they are *not* behaving as I expect.

The page, very dumbed down for this example, is here:

http://littleduck.com/ns_sample/index.html

On this example, there is just the home page and the "Services" page. You can link back and forth between them.

If you mouseover those grey links on the left (which are called "balloons" in the code), you will see that they have a hover color, and a popup graphic appears. I ONLY want this to happen when the page is in the "home" position. I have a class called "popup_yes" that allows this hover/popup action to happen. It appears when index.html is loaded, and if I remove it or change its name in the code, the hover/popup does not work. So I know that class is doing something. Now, I REMOVE that class when "Services" is clicked. I can see by inspecting the element in Chrome that "popup_yes" DOES in fact get removed. HOWEVER ... the hover/popup action still happens when you mouseover the balloons.

And when I inspect the element, even though you can see in the code that "popup_yes" is gone, it is still being utilized by Chrome. Here is a screenshot of what Inspect Element looks like on the "home" and "inside" pages:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1ZP7.jpg

So, please tell me where my brain is derailing. How can I get the hover/popup action to NOT WORK when I'm on the "Services" page? Thank you incredibly much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your mouseover/out code

```
$(".popup_yes .balloon_1").mouseover(function() {
    $("#popup_1").show(400);
    $(".balloon_1").addClass("hover");
});
```

When the page loads, the mouseover event is binding to that span, so that action is already established, if you add the check in the function

```
$(".popup_yes .balloon_1").mouseover(function() {
    if ($('#balloons').hasClass('popup_yes') ){ //<--here
        $("#popup_1").show(400);
        $(".balloon_1").addClass("hover");
    }
    });
```

it should work as expected

Comment: TThis makes sense now ... thank you very much. You solved my immediate problem and I learned something valuable!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the javascript that you are using and could make it work. Here are the changes that i made.

First of all when u removed the class when the services page is clicked I specified the class to be removed.

```
$('#balloons').removeClass("popup_yes");
```

After this when you click back the Home page the class has to be added back so i included this line after you animate the `$('#buttons')` div.

```
$("#balloons").addClass("popup_yes");
```

Now comes the changing of the hover effect on each of the balloons. I'll show the change I did to the first balloon element you can reproduce the same for the others.

```
$(".balloon_1").mouseover(function() {
   if($(this).closest('#balloons').attr("class")=="popup_yes"){
      $("#popup_1").show(400);
      $(".balloon_1").addClass("hover");
     }
 });

$(".balloon_1").mouseout(function() {
    if($(this).closest('#balloons').attr("class")=="popup_yes"){
        $("#popup_1").hide(400);
        $(".balloon_1").removeClass("hover");
     }
});
```

What I modified is instead of checking for both the class for hovering I just checked the `balloon_1` class and then I made the effect only if the closest element to it with an id `balloons` has the class `popup_yes`.

I tried it in chrome. Hope it works well in other browsers as well.